# How to customize the magit-todo display

Tags: magit, highlighting

I use Emacs to write documentation, and a lot of times my files end up with some internal markup that looks like this: `[TK: Where is the event handler defined?]` in-line with the text. ([“TK” is writer speak for “to come”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_come_(publishing)), since the only common English words that have ‘tk’ in them are “pocketknife” and “hotkey”, and case sensitivity matters.)

I added “TK” to `hl-todo-keyword-faces`, but I discovered that `hl-todo` uses a regexp like `(^|\s)(<keyword>)`, so the opening bracket confuses `hl-todo`, and it doesn’t show up in the todo lists.

I wrote a quick perl script to place a space before the bracket, and it worked, and now the `magit-status` buffer says my documentation folder has 59 TODOs over 41 markdown files – which is great! – but it won’t list them like it does in source code, which is not great.

So:

1. Remembering to write the space in `[ TK: ...]` is a pain in the neck, and looks terrible. Is there a way to modify the regexp such that the opening bracket is a legal character to `hl-todo` without hacking `hl-todo`’s source in the Elpa folder?

<s>2.  Has anyone seen this where Magit-todo won’t list the TODOs? What do I do? I’m not the world’s greatest Elisp hacker, and it’s always good to task first before trying to figure out for myself.</s> Nevermind, this was just me not understanding the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

The space issue is an inconsistency in the way magit-todos and hl-todos generate their regular expressions.  [I have submitted a pull request](https://github.com/alphapapa/magit-todos/pull/125).